# Flutter location

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, location

As you know in android devices we've got to type of location permission,

```java
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

The first one is for using normal location and the second one it's for a special time for example battery low or...,
I want to use the only second one in my flutter application,

Can anybody give me the solution or give me advice if I'm wrong,

Answer (score 0):

There is a great package you can use, [geolocator.](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)

You can read the documentation on the pub.dev page, but they have a `desiredAccuracy` option.

```dart
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

Make sure to adjust the accuracy and read the docs to fit your use case.